# What gets written to the log files in Rails. What can you do with them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I see some log files in a log folder in Rails. What are some common useful things that I can do with these logs? These files are usually in a gitignore right so that whatever logs get created in production are uncorrupted right? If so, these logs contain the true logs of the production site. What can be done with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article about how to make your logs more useful but to answer your question. I use the logs mainly to find out errors and bugs. I found a lot of them that are not really obvious like failed background transactions, performance issues and even some legacy code that gets triggered.

For logs are a great place to find all these things and try figure out a better solution.

Here is the blog post on how to make the logs better:
http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2015/12/09/4-ways-to-get-the-most-out-of-your-rails-logs

I also suggest using New Relic which really helps you monitor your App.